# Binding Javafx on focus lost

Tags: javafx

In swing we could bind component and pojo for instance

```
org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, wb, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${TSB_NAME}"), edTSB, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text_ON_ACTION_OR_FOCUS_LOST"));
    bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
```

I'm interested in FOCUS_LOST thing. What in JavaFX about it?

Comment: The code fragment you post is not useful for JavaFX only developers. Please concretize your purpose of the question. The `Node` has a `focusProperty`  which can be used in bindings. What do you want to do on focus lost?

Comment: I want executing binding when focus lost from textfield.

Comment: and what is the task that you want to do when the focus is lost from the textfield?

Comment: when something changed in target object (pojo) It's need to change text in textfield. If textfield losted focus then change field in pojo, but only when focus lost.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any third-party libraries for JavaFX that have exactly the same functionality as the one for Swing that you are referencing in the question. JavaFX has built-in mechanisms for observing and binding properties: however what you are describing is not a true binding as the two properties (one in the POJO, one in the `TextField`) do not always have the same value: while the user is typing and before focus is transferred they will be different. Thus you have to implement this with listeners, rather than bindings.

If you implement your POJO using the [JavaFX property pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107), i.e. you have something like

```
public class MyEntity {

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text ;
    }
    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    // other properties...
}
```

then you can do the following:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();

textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
    if (! isNowFocused) {
        entity.setText(textField.getText());
    }
});
entity.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
    textField.setText(newText));
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that It can be done without binding.

Comment: It can't be done with binding, since the values are sometimes different. A binding is implemented as one or more listeners anyway